# Passing server parameters as arquillian resource?

Tags: java, functional-testing, jboss-arquillian

I'm using arquillian for functional tests only. Arquillian is not managing a container (standalone) and is not deploying an app (also done manually. Since there's no deployment I can't obtain `deploymentUrl` using `@ArquillianResource`.

Also, it's a maven project and I have a property with server hostname which is pretty much what I need to get in arquillian test.

My question is: what would be another option to acquire a url except for hard coding it?

Answer (score 1):

If the tests are run in client JVM, you can probably use system properties. For example, with maven it could be:

```
$ mvn test -Ddeployment.url=http://whatever
```

And in test code:

```
String url = System.getProperty("deployment.url", "http://defaulturl");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's exactly how it's done today. However this is a workaround, once host is changed it is needed to change the system property+arquilian.xml. I'm hoping for a solution. :P

Comment: This answer doesn't need changes in arquillian.xml

Comment: Well I'm setting up the server in the arquilian.xml which I imagine is impossible to live without atm, thus once changed you will need to change the property and the config file. If you found a different way please share.

Comment: @DenysS. well, you say you start your server manually and deploy manually, then you don't need arquillian.xml (at least for server configuration).

Comment: have you tried running arquilian without server specified in the config?

Comment: Of course: https://github.com/tsabirgaliev/javaee-6-maven/blob/master/src/test/resources/arquillian.xml